# How to broadcast a linux machine on LAN before wifi or ethernet connection

Tags: linux, networking, wifi, nmcli, mobile

If I have a mobile app, capable of scanning devices on my LAN, how can I set up my linux machine (to be present as a device on the LAN), lets say a Raspberry Pi, so that the mobile app can help the machine to connect to WiFi.

From the machine I can connect to WiFi with `nmcli`

`nmcli dev wifi connect <AP name> password <password>`

And this gives the machine an IP on the LAN.

This is not what I need. I want that when the linux machine is introduced first time in a LAN, without any changes from the machine, I want to connect it to WiFi from my mobile app. An example of this is how Amazon Echo devices connect to Wifi.

Comment: You mean something like this? https://blog.thegaragelab.com/esp8266-network-configuration/

Comment: @ibuprofen thanks this seems like what I am looking for. Seems quite advanced though and is specific to arduino, do you know how this can be done on linux - I'm assuming on a linux machine should be simpler

Comment: I do not have any answer out of the box, it was more to clarify what you are actually asking. You would perhaps like to change the sentence "*without any changes from the machine*" - as it could be read like you want this to be done without doing any pre-stup to the device. It is also not *"on your LAN"* as it is not connected at all (if I read you correctly).

Comment: Yeah I didn't know how to express what I needed :) But I think you put me in the right direction - On debian I can set the server as Access Point, I think that can work
https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/debian-ubuntu-linux-setting-wireless-access-point/